# Adding for loop to sed process

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

Have a script

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -E 's/([^,]*,([^,]*),) ?(([[:alpha:]])[^ ]* +)(([^,]*),[^,]*,)[^,]*/\1\u\3\u\5\L\4\6\2@example.com/' file.csv > output.csv
```

Have a file.csv:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,directorate
1,1, Amy Lee,Singer,,, 
2,2,brad Pitt,Actor,bpitt@example.com,Production 
3,5,steven spielberg,Producer,Screenwriter, spielberg@yahoo.com,Production
4,8,Andy lee,Comedian,,Radio
```

A few problem, that I need resolve:

- title value can be more than one title, example: Steve Spielberg - Producer,Screenwriter. Now the script cuts off the value after the comma, but I need to save all titles.
- script concatenate first letter of first name and a last name, plus location_id and @google.com, but I need add location_id, only when have a equals emails.

In the end it should be:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,directorate
1,1, Amy Lee,Singer,alee1@example.com,, 
2,2,Brad Pitt,Actor,bpitt@example.com,Production 
3,5,Steven Spielberg,Producer,Screenwriter,sspielberg@example.com,Production
4,8,Andy Lee,Comedian,alee8@example.com,Radio
```

Comment: If you can have commas in the field of a CSV file, the field should be delimited with quotes. Unfortunately, regular expressions are generally not powerful enough to parse formats like that.

Comment: Generally not solvable imo. The floating entries could be associated to any column. Even if you check the `@` in email and deduce its location you're out of luck if the email is missing.

Comment: @AndreWildberg maybe not with sed? Is there any other way to solve this problem from the start?

Comment: With a lot of assumptions (e.g. names have spaces etc) it could be solved for a special case/file. But there is no stable general approach other than a correct user input with quotes around the field. Imagine this entry `,,,,,,,,,,`. Which one is the entry with comma inside a field? Only correct user input will tell you e.g. `,,,",,,,,",,`

Comment: Making up random email addresses is a bad idea; you end up having spammers pick them up and send unwanted messages to real people if those addresses happen to be taken. Use @example.com for examples; it's guaranteed to not have this problem.

Comment: Determine the boundaries of a field: Is `title` the only field that can have commas inside? Use location_id only when email is not unique: Don't uise line-oriented `sed`, use something like `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that directorate doesn't contain commas:

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*,([0-9]+), *([[:alpha:]])[^ ]* *([[:alpha:]]*).*,)(,[^,]*$)/\1\3\4\2@example.com\5/'
```

This *always* adds the location id number. It is possible to do it only for duplicate example emails by adding a second filter. Also consider using ID (first column) instead, in case of duplicate location + name.

Comment: and how I can add a new filter?